# Difference between scientific python and scipy?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I'm installing MMTK (Molecular Modeling tool Kit) and it requires scientific python.

What are the difference (if any) between "scientific python" and scipy? Is scientific python just the older version of SciPy?

It also requires "Numeric python", which now resolves to NumPy.

Comment: As of today, it may be of notice that [ScientificPython has not seen an update since 2014](https://sourcesup.renater.fr/projects/scientific-py/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that MMTK comes from CNRS Orleans, "Scientific Python" is probably [this library](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/plone/software/scientificpython/) from the same institute. It's unrelated to SciPy, AFAIK.

"Numeric Python" is one of the predecessors of NumPy, which still offers a backwards compatible API.